# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'history/createBrowserHistory'

Tags: reactjs

I tried using `history` but I am getting these errors when I run command `npm start`:

```
ERROR in ./index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'history/createBrowserHistory' in '/Users/macbookpro/Desktop/coding/giphy-master'
 @ ./index.js 41:28-67
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8081 ./index.js
```

Comment: `npm install history` ?

Comment: `npm i react-router-dom`

Comment: thanks alot but still not working

Answer (score 0):

```
// import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
//  Error: Cannot find module 'history/createBrowserHistory';

// change it
import { createBrowserHistory  as createHistory} from 'history';

const app = dva({
  history: createHistory(),
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).