# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'history/createBrowserHistory' on Router component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Trying to create a plain router with default history object, but its throwing this error -

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'history/createBrowserHistory'

In the App.js file -

```
import history from './history'

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div className="ui container" style={{marginTop: '50px'}}>
            <Router history={history}>
                <Header />
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" exact element={<StreamList />} />
                </Routes>
            </Router>
        </div>
    );
};
```

In the history.js file -

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'

export default createHistory();
```

I also tried the solution mentioned in [Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'history/createBrowserHistory'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67535590/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-history-createbrowserhistory), but now its not rendering the App component at all, and getting the following error in console

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname') at Router

What could be the reason? I installed a separate history dependency, but its still not working.

Comment: It seems you are using `react-router-dom@6`, what version of `history` did you install? Have you tried `import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you've incorrectly imported the `createBrowserHistory` utility function. The named `createBrowserHistory` export should be imported.

history.js

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export default createBrowserHistory();
```

With the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'pathname') at Router

I suspect you've not imported the correct router component. All the high-level routers (*`BrowserRouter`, `HashRouter`, etc..*) all instantiate and maintain an internal `history` reference, and the low-level `Router` has a few required props, none of which are `history`. Import and use the  [HistoryRouter](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/routers/history-router) and provide your custom history object as a prop.

app.js

```
import { unstable_HistoryRouter as HistoryRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import history from './history';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="ui container" style={{ marginTop: '50px' }}>
      <HistoryRouter history={history}>
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<StreamList />} />
        </Routes>
      </HistoryRouter>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

About issue:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'history/createBrowserHistory'

I think issue is in a name of history module. There is not a module with a name 'history/createBrowserHistory'. Try that instead:

```js
//history.js
import {createBrowserHistory} from 'history'

export default createBrowserHistory()
```

About issue:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'pathname') at Router

If you use react-router 6 then Router component does not have history in its props. You may try something like that:

```js
<Router location={history.location} navigator={history}>
```

But, I would recommend to follow that advice - https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/router

Comment: Thanks, yeah the App component is now rendering. However, the routes are not working when a <Link> button is clicked that points to a specific path. The url changes, but doesn't really render the component at that path. BUT the routes are working if i visit the link from browser url manually.

Note - I am not using any of the high-level routers because i need to history object to do programmatic navigation when an action creator is called, as in the user fills the form and upon successful request, navigate them back to another url.

Comment: that is expected. Check implementation of BrowserRouter - https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/6b44e99f0b659428ce2ec8d5098e90c7fddda2c5/packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx#L148

you should use history.listen to update location props of Router. But anyway I think I could answer your initial question.